# How to write Mongo DB query that compares embedded documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

Consider an Order document with many LineItems embedded documents and a single SpecialLineItem embedded document.

To find Orders with LineItems of a given type, this works:

```
find({ 'lineItems.type' : 'food' })
```

How to find Orders where at least one LineItem type is ***not*** the same as the SpecialLineItem type?

Also, some Orders have no LineItems.

For example, find this document:

```
lineItems: { type:food },
           { type:wood }
specialLineItem: { type: food }
```

But not:

```
lineItems: { type:food }
specialLineItem: { type: food }
```

or

```
lineItems: []
specialLineItem: { type: food }
```

Comment: If this were really common, the most efficient way would be to add a field that is updated when the document is saved that contains whether the condition is true/false. You could use a Map-Reduce to do the filter. It would just produce a list of matching document `_id`s. You might be able to use a `$where` in the `find` which would execute JavaScript. However, it would never be efficient and would require a complete collection scan and JavaScript execution for every document.

Comment: After working on it for a while, I found that $where will work because the other conditions reduce the size of documents to a small number. I don't want to add a field because it makes clutters the embedded document. Map-Reduce seems like a lot of work...

Comment: argh, 3 minutes to write that method and the whole world can see it...

Comment: "Cluttering" the document? I see it as an "optimizing" field. :) It's all point of view.

Answer (score 1):

> How to find Orders where at least one LineItem type is not the same as the SpecialLineItem type?

That's not really possible. You will have to store that information when you insert or update the document.

However, you can use the [`$where` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) or just pass in a javascript method. However, this is utterly slow because it will have to perform a full collection scan:

```
db.coll.find(function() { for(var i = 0; i < this.lineItems.length; i++){ 
  if(this.lineItems[i].type != this.specialLineItem.type) {
        return true; } 
  } 
  return false;
}).pretty();
```

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in my comment, I would recommend adding a field that, at document save/update time, is updated to reflect the answer to this query. Indexed, it would be super fast to answer the question.

Here's a simple example of map-reduce code that would provide a collection of matching document `_id`s, and the special line item that matched:

```
map = function() {
    var items = this.lineitems || [];
    var match = this.specialLineItem.type;
    for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (match === items[i].type) {
            emit(this._id, match);
            return;
        }
    }
};

reduce = function(key, values) {
   return values;  
};
```

Using:

```
db.test.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: 'test2' })
```

Results in something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530276101378b009f17ff653"), "value" : "food" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530276341378b009f17ff656"), "value" : "food" }
```